# How to write unit test cases for any real time Java app?

Tags: java, unit-testing

With lack of real time experience in developing a Java application, I would like to understand the testing strategy for any written module made of multiple classes. Below is the sample application that i learnt from a training,

```
/* SList.java */

/**
 * The SList class is a singly-linked list implementation of the linked list
 * abstraction. SLists are mutable data structures, which can grow at either
 * end. 
 * @author mohet01
 *
 */
public class SList{
    private SListNode head;
    private int size;

    /**
     * SList() constructs an empty list.
     */

    public SList(){
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    /**
     * isEmpty() indicates whether the list is empty.
     * @return true is the list is empty, false otherwise.
     */
    public boolean isEmpty(){
        return size == 0;
    }

    /**
     * length() returns the length of this list.
     * @return the length of the list.
     */
    public int length(){
        return size;
    }

    /**
     * insertFront() inserts item "obj" at the beginning of this list.
     * @param obj the item to be inserted.
     */

    public void insertFront(Object obj){
        this.head = new SListNode(obj, this.head);
        this.size++;
    }

    /**
     * insertEnd() inserts item "obj" at the end of this list.
     * @param obj the item to be inserted.
     */
    public void insertEnd(Object obj){
        if(head == null){
            this.head = new SListNode(obj);
        }else{
            SListNode node = this.head;
            while(node.next != null){
                node = node.next;
            }
            node.next = new SListNode(obj);
        }
        size++;
    }

    /**
     * nth() returns the item at the specified position. If position < 1 or
     * position > this.length(), null is returned. Otherwise, item at 
     * position "position" is returned. The list does not change.
     * @param position the desired position, from 1 to length(), in the list.
     * @return the item at the given position in the list.
     */

    public Object nth(int position){
        if((position < 1) || (position > this.length()) || this.head == null){
            return null;
        }else{
            SListNode currentNode = this.head;
            while(position > 1){
                currentNode = currentNode.next;
                if(currentNode == null)
                    return null;
                position--;
            }
            return currentNode.item;
        }
    }


    /**
     * toString() converts the list to String.
     * @return a string representation of the list.
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        Object obj;
        String result = "[ ";

        SListNode currentNode = head;

        while(currentNode != null){
            obj = currentNode.item;
            result = result + obj.toString() + " ";
            currentNode = currentNode.next;
        }
        result = result + " ]";
        return result;
    }


    /**
     * main() runs test cases on SList class. Prints summary
     * information on basic operations and halts with an error (and a stack
     * trace) if any of the tests fail. 
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args){


        testEmpty();
        testAfterInsertFront();
        testAfterInsertEnd();
    }

    /**
     * testEmpty() tests toString(), isEmpty(), length(), insertFront(), and
     * insertEnd() on an empty list. Prints summary information of the tests 
     * and halts the program if errors are detected.
     */
    private static void testEmpty(){
        SList lst1 = new SList();
        SList lst2 = new SList();
        System.out.println();
        lst1.toString();
        System.out.println("Here is a list after construction: " 
                + lst1.toString());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.toString().equals("[  ]"),
                  "toString on newly constructed list failed");
        System.out.println("isEmpty() should be true. It is: " +
                   lst1.isEmpty());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.isEmpty() == true,
                  "isEmpty() on newly constructed list failed");    
        System.out.println("length() should be 0. It is: " +
                   lst1.length());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.length() == 0, 
                  "length on newly constructed list failed");    
        lst1.insertFront(new Integer(3));
        System.out.println("Here is a list after insertFront(3) to an empty list: "
                   + lst1.toString());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.toString().equals("[  3  ]"),
                  "InsertFront on empty list failed");
        lst2.insertEnd(new Integer(5));
        System.out.println("Here is a list after insertEnd(5) on an empty list: "
                   + lst2.toString());
        TestHelper.verify(lst2.toString().equals("[  5  ]"),
                  "insertEnd on empty list failed");
    }


    /**
     * testAfterInsertFront() tests toString(), isEmpty(), length(),
     * insertFront(), and insertEnd() after insertFront(). Prints summary
     * information of the tests and halts the program if errors are detected. 
     */
    private static void testAfterInsertFront(){
        SList lst1 = new SList();
        lst1.insertFront(new Integer(3));
        lst1.insertFront(new Integer(2));
        lst1.insertFront(new Integer(1));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Here is a list after insertFront 3, 2, 1: "
                + lst1.toString());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.toString().equals("[  1  2  3  ]"), "InsertFronts on non-empty list failed");
        System.out.println("isEmpty() should be false. It is: " +
                lst1.isEmpty());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.isEmpty() == false, 
                "isEmpty() after insertFront failed");
        System.out.println("length() should be 3. It is: " +
                lst1.length());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.length() == 3, 
                "length() after insertFront failed");
        lst1.insertEnd(new Integer(4));
        System.out.println("Here is the same list after insertEnd(4): "
                   + lst1.toString());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.toString().equals("[  1  2  3  4  ]"),
                  "insertEnd on non-empty list failed");
    }

    /**
       *  testAfterInsertEnd() tests toString(), isEmpty(), length(),
       *  insertFront(), and insertEnd() after insertEnd().  Prints summary
       *  information of the tests and halts the program if errors are detected.
       **/

      private static void testAfterInsertEnd() {
        SList lst1 = new SList();
        lst1.insertEnd(new Integer(6));
        lst1.insertEnd(new Integer(7));
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Here is a list after insertEnd 6, 7: "
                   + lst1.toString());
        System.out.println("isEmpty() should be false. It is: " +
                   lst1.isEmpty());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.isEmpty() == false,
                  "isEmpty() after insertEnd failed");    
        System.out.println("length() should be 2. It is: " +
                   lst1.length());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.length() == 2, 
                  "length() after insertEndfailed");
        lst1.insertFront(new Integer(5));
        System.out.println("Here is the same list after insertFront(5): "
                   + lst1.toString());
        TestHelper.verify(lst1.toString().equals("[  5  6  7  ]"),
                  "insertFront after insertEnd failed");
      }

}
```

---

```
/* TestHelper.java */

/**
 * This class is based on code from Arnow/Dexter/Weiss. Its verify() method 
 * exits with an error message if an invariant fails to hold true.
 * 
 * The purpose of this class is to provide a shorthand for writing and testing 
 * invariants in any program.
 *
 */
public class TestHelper{
    static void verify(boolean invariant, String message){
        if(!invariant){
            System.out.println("*** ERROR:  " + message);
            Thread.dumpStack();
        }
    }
}
```

where a list abstraction `SList` is being unit tested with below 3 calls

```
testEmpty();
testAfterInsertFront();
testAfterInsertEnd();
```

My question:

Does it take similar approach to unit test the module that is written by developer in any real time application? Based on above code, Do you think unit testing strategy can be made better?

Note: Please let me know, if `SListNode` class has to be shown as part of this query.

Comment: This is too short to be a full-fledged answer, but there are testing frameworks/utilities like JUnit, TestNG and Hamcrest matchers, so that you do not need to roll your own `TestHelper` class.

Comment: This question seems to be about the conceptual design and implementation of unit testing as best practice in the industry and not about a code review

Comment: @Vogel612 which is the right place to pose such queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, here's my slightly more fleshed out answer after my comment...

**Just to repeat: there are testing frameworks/utilities like [JUnit](http://junit.org/), [TestNG](http://testng.org/doc/index.html) and [Hamcrest matchers](http://hamcrest.org/JavaHamcrest/), so that you do not need to roll your own `TestHelper` class.**

1. You don't have to write `boolCondition == true` or `boolCondition == false`, to test for `true` conditions, they can simply be expressed as `boolCondition` and `!boolCondition` respectively.
2. *Asserting* via the `toString()` representation may look like it works now, but the proper way is to override your class's `equals()` method (and as [a form of habit](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), `hashCode()` too). Your `toString()` representation may change in the future, which means you'll have to update your test cases.
3. Test cases usually belong to their own class, e.g. `SListTest`.
4. Why do you need to `dumpStack()` when only the assertion is `false`? Maybe I only accidentally compared `1 == 2`, and I'm not expecting any stack dump...

Comment: Is `JUnit` used for only developers who does Unit testing? Or Does `JUnit` used by testing technicians for `System testing` `Integration testing` `Black-box testing` `White-box testing` `Regression testing` `Automation testing` `User acceptance testing` `Software performance testing` ?

Comment: Wells, the other testing you mentioned usually build upon many unit tests for many classes (except for black-box/white-box, are you really required to perform those? or are you just quoting from somewhere else?), so I will say `JUnit` is pretty much used for all kinds of testing.

Comment: yes you are right, i have quoted this testing phases from wiki, as i do not know what they are, But they exist in testing phase. So, Are you saying that java code written for Unit tests(as part of JUnit framework) will be wrapped by additional java code to perform integration/performance/scale/.. testing?

Comment: Just to keep my answer-comment concise, integration tests can be done by a Continuous Integration server that polls your source code repository, downloads any updates, and runs the integration tests for you. You wouldn't be writing additional Java code in that case. :) Of course there'll be some configuration for said server, and what to test/not test, but those are not code.

Comment: so you mean test cases should be configurable rather than writing code for each test case? Does `JUnit` package help us find new updates in source code, if source code sits in remote windows box that has the complete source code? Another question, Does JUnit work with only in testing java application, Does it have capability to test both C&Java applications, Because mostly real time applications are multilingual?

Comment: You may want to join our chat rooms to discuss that further... but nope, `JUnit` is a Java-based unit testing framework for unit testing only. It's not a Continuous Integration server.

Comment: Or actually, if you have more general questions about unit testing and other kinds of testing, do consider http://programmers.stackexchange.com/ .

Comment: @overexchange No, JUnit can do about nothing. But it's surely sufficient for the start as you need: 1. quickly run a test for the new/changed class directly from your IDE, 2. run all tests e.g. before pushing to server (10-100 times per day). Continuous integration at al is the next step, which gets relevant when you have thousands of tests.

Comment: @overexchange And why does some funny windows box have all the sources? Are you having terabytes of sources so it doesn't fit into your box or are you using some abstruse source control?

Answer (score 2):

Using JUnit4 for [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing) is very easy. Add the Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
    <version>4.11</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

Convert your test helper to JUnit assertions, for example:

```
import org.junit.Test;

import static org.junit.Assert.assertEquals;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertTrue;

public class SListTest {
    @Test
    public void testEmptyList() {
        SList lst1 = new SList();
        assertEquals("toString on newly constructed list failed", "[  ]", lst1.toString());
        assertTrue("isEmpty() on newly constructed list failed", lst1.isEmpty());
        assertEquals("length on newly constructed list failed", 0, lst1.length());
        lst1.insertFront(3);
        assertEquals("InsertFront on empty list failed", "[ 3  ]", lst1.toString());
        SList lst2 = new SList();
        lst2.insertEnd(5);
        assertEquals("insertEnd on empty list failed", "[ 5  ]", lst2.toString());
    }
}
```

Run the tests in your IDE (something like right-click on the test class, Run Tests), or with Maven on the command line:

```
mvn test
```

I often talk about the benefits of unit testing, and I often start code review by writing unit tests for the code under question. After I have the tests that verify the behavior, I start refactoring, and see what breaks. It's easy when unit tests have your back.

Comment: am not aware of `maven dependency` am new to Java

Comment: So, JUnit just provides some ready made methods like comparing, which is already done in my code?

Comment: All IDEs have built-in support for JUnit tests. You can skip what I said about Maven, though you would benefit from it greatly. In your IDE if you right-click on a class with @Test annotations, you should have an option to run unit tests, and you'll get a nice user interface with the test cases executed and their result in red (failure) and green (success). You get this out of the box if you use JUnit.